# Running parse server with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an scenario in which I need parse server to be run from a Dockerfile, and that docker file should be run inside docker-compose. Also, I need to externalize configuration to a json file.

The main problem is that if I run this Dockerfile inside docker-compose, config file is not found.

This is my dockerfile declaration:

```
FROM parseplatform/parse-server:4.2.0

COPY config.json config.json

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["/parse-server/bin/parse-server", "config.json"]
```

This is my config.json file:

```
{
  "appId": "appId",
  "masterKey": "masterKey",
  "databaseURI": "mongodb://usr:pass@mongodb:27017"
}
```

This is working properly, as if I build it and the run this:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t parse  .

docker run --name parse  -p 1337:1337 -d parse config.json
```

It works properly, and in a nutshell, the important line from the docker logs is this:

```
Configuration loaded from /parse-server/config.json
```

But if I try to run it inside a docker-compose file this way:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: usr
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass

  parse:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    depends_on:
      - db
```

It doesn't work, it just prints parse-server help, along with this line:

```
Configuration loaded from /parse-server/bin/parse-server
```

I've tested a couple of scenarios (note: doesn't work means here that the config file is not found):

1. Declaring a command inside docker-compose to run parse-server, and give the **--appId**, **--masterKey** and **--databaseURI** switches manually, it works.
2. Declaring a command inside docker-compose pointing to the config.json file doesn't work.
3. Mount config.json file inside docker-compose container via volumes, doesn't work.
4. Running a command with the previously mentioned switched, and then inspect the container itself to check if the file is there, and yes, it is.
5. Copy the file to where parse-server should take it by default ( **/parse-server/bin** )

Questions:

1. There is a slighty chance that config file is being copy after the parse-server command execution?
2. How can it be that the Dockerfile alone works fine, and it doesn't work inside a docker-compose file? As far as I know, it wouldn't be that harder, as this is the proper way to run it.
3. Any hints about what is wrong with this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: usr
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass

  parse:
    build: .
    command: "config.json"
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`command` will override the `CMD` in `Dockerfile`.

Or if you don't want to specify the command over here, you can change your Dockerfile.

```
FROM parseplatform/parse-server:4.2.0

COPY config.json config.json

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["config.json"].  # Changed
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, but, why? I though that command here just substitutes the Dockerfile command. How to just giving the json file name is working?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'll edit my answer and `command` in `dokcer-compose.yml` overrides the Dockerfile `CMD`

Answer (score 1):

To go through your questions:

1. No, the actual `parse-server` command is executed at runtime of the container, the copy command is run at build-time of the image
2. The command you are running through docker is different than the one you are running in your compose command: `config.json` and `/parse-server/bin/parse-server config.json`, respectively

I'd change your docker-compose to mirror what you are running with docker:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: usr
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass

  parse:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    depends_on:
      - db
    # this is exactly what you are handing to vanilla docker
    command: "config.json"
```

and run it like `docker-compose up -d`

However, I think your suggestion of using a volume is a bit better, that way a configuration change doesn't require re-building the image:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: usr
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass

  parse:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - parse_vol:/path/to/config  # config is a folder in the container, mind you
    command: "/path/to/config/config.json"


volumes:
  parse_vol:
    driver: local
    driver-opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /local/path/to/config  # this is also a folder that contains config.json
```